# Everything is orange when I "Try Ubuntu"

Tags: system-installation, live-usb

I'm about to install Ubuntu, but when I selected *Try Ubuntu* the screen contrast was very orangey?

[image: tomatoey coloured desktop background]

How can I fix it?

Is it still safe to download Ubuntu?

Comment: Install Ubuntu, then if you have an Nvidia GPU, install proprietary drivers and switch output to RGB. Or change input in monitor settings. Color space should be same.

Comment: in the grub screen, choose install ubuntu with safe graphics. that should help.

Comment: This ^^^but it's actually "Try Ubuntu (with safe graphics)" then make sure to select the option to install 3rd party drivers, firmware, codecs, etc. The visual glitch has nothing to do with security so your last question is nonsensical.